# How to name a method that does getting and removal from the collection?

Tags: naming-conventions

How to name a method that does getting and removal from the collection?

Say we have a collection Fruits. To get apples we would do something like apples = Fruits.Get("apples"). To remove - Fruits.Remove("apples"). If we want to do both in one method it would return apples and remove them form the collection. Something like apples = Fruits.Take("apples"). Any better ideas than "Take"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either remove() or take() are fine.

For example:

- In java.util.Map, the [remove()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) method gets and removes an object specified by a key.
- In JavaSpaces, the [take*()](http://www.jini.org/wiki/JavaSpaces_Specification#takeIfExists_and_take) methods get and remove and object specified by a template.

Answer (score 1):

pop(index) seems a reasonable misuse of stack's method to me.

Comment: why do you think it is a misuse?

Comment: @Al Bundy - Because then it looks like a stack

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat language specific but something like:

```
Object remove(int index)
```